# Google Action returning Empty Speech Response

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am receiving this response from my Google Action and I am unable to figure out why an empty response would be sent out. My Intents all seem to have the right webhooks and default responses where needed.

```
{
 insertId:  "hrf6g3f6f1zhg"  
 labels: {
  channel:  "production"   
  querystream:  "GOOGLE_USER"   
  source:  "AOG_REQUEST_RESPONSE"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/math-164823/logs/actions.googleapis.com%2Factions"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-08-01T13:05:42.164452044Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   action_id:  "assistant.intent.action.TEXT"    
   project_id:  "math-164823"    
   version_id:  ""    
  }
  type:  "assistant_action"   
 }
 severity:  "DEBUG"  
 textPayload:  "Received response from agent with body: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.13.6
Date: Wed, 01 Aug 2018 13:05:42 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 494
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: f0727cf8856a9fa6cbf1f0e861c14836/7685757289520895586;o=0
Google-Assistant-API-Version: v1
Assistant-Interaction-Error-Code: -1
Assistant-Interaction-Error-Message: Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of Empty speech response
Via: 1.1 google
Alt-Svc: clear

{
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "code": 10,
      "message": "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of Empty speech response",
      "details": [{
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Value",
        "value": "{\"id\":\"c132e91a-4918-4720-ae54-8deacd5bd59e\",\"timestamp\":\"2018-08-01T13:05:41.908Z\",\"lang\":\"en\",\"result\":{},\"status\":{\"code\":200,\"errorType\":\"success\"},\"sessionId\":\"1533128627128\"}"
      }]
    }
  }
}."  
 timestamp:  "2018-08-01T13:05:42.106660479Z"  
 trace:  "projects/368086278893/traces/1533128627128"  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to diagnose the problem without seeing all of your Intents and the code you are using in your fulfillment, but a few things to look for in this case:

- Make sure your Intents either have a Response set in the response section, or the switch saying to use a fulfillment webhook is turned on.
- Make sure your Intents all have a function in the webhook that is supposed to return something.
- If you are making asynchronous calls (such as calls to APIs that run on other servers), make sure you are using Promises and that you are returning a Promise as part of your intent handler.
- Check the logs for your webhook. Make sure there are no errors logged when it runs. If necessary, add logging to make sure you're returning what you think you're returning.
- You may wish to run your webhook with a proxy, such as ngrok, in between so you can get detailed request and response logs and see the exact JSON that your code is sending back.
- Turn on Dialogflow's feature to log to Google Cloud's StackDriver.

Answer (score 0):

Try and enable V2 for Google Assistant in Dialogflow integration. If your Dialogflow agent is Old while integrating enable as per the below-highlighted section.

[image]

If this is not working, update your question with Dialogflow intents, Settings, Webhook code and version of the client.